# How to get number of NIC's and their information

Tags: vbscript, nic

As the title states, I am looking for a way for a VBScript to count the number of NICs there are on a computer and return their information. At the very least I would like to get the number of NICs.

Answer (score 0):

Query WMI:

```
Dim wmi, items, item, count

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set items = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter")

count = 0

For Each item in items 
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & item.Name
    count = count + 1
Next

Wscript.Echo "Count: " & count
```

Comment: Is there a reason why this displays more NIC's than what my device manager is displaying?